# Выдает ошибку при запуске ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'faker'

Tags: python

```py
import faker

fake = Faker('ru')
```

Выдает ошибку при запуске:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'faker'

Хотя у меня оно установлено.

Comment: Логичный вопрос — почему вы решили что установлено? Как установлено? В правильном ли виртуальном окружении установлено?

Comment: в настройках питона , в плагинах установил , пробовал -pip install Faker , удалял и заново устанавливал , не помогает

Comment: Что такое «настройки питона»? Что такое «плагины»? В питоне нет ни того ни другого. Где запускали pip? В правильном ли виртуальном окружении?

Comment: в pycharm (файл - настройки - плагины)